# There is a way to start contentScrim animation sooner on CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-support-design

In this example the contentScrim attribute is set with a color, but I can't figure out how to control when it starts. I woud like to start the color transition sooner.

[image: contentScrim example]

Can you give me a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to make the color appear sooner?

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to create a class that extends `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. Something like this (you might need to adjust that so it exactly fits your needs):

```
public class CustomCollapsingToolbarLayout extends CollapsingToolbarLayout {

    public static interface Listener {
        public void onContentScrimAnimationStarted(boolean showing);
    }

    private Listener mListener;

    public CustomCollapsingToolbarLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomCollapsingToolbarLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomCollapsingToolbarLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setScrimsShown(boolean shown, boolean animate) {
        super.setScrimsShown(shown, animate);
        if (animate && mListener != null) {
            mListener.onContentScrimAnimationStarted(shown);
        }
    }

    public void setListener(Listener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    } 
}
```

And just call `setListener` on your `CustomCollapsingToolbarLayout` instance.

```
CustomCollapsingToolbarLayout mToolbarLayout = 
                    (CustomCollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
mToolbarLayout.setListener(new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onContentScrimAnimationStarted(boolean showing) {
        //do what you want
    }
});
```

---

**EDIT** (actually answering the question):

Modify the `scrimVisibleHeightTrigger` value (with the [`setScrimVisibleHeightTrigger`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html#setScrimVisibleHeightTrigger(int)) method of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`) to change the starting point of the animation.

Comment: Hi Bartosz, thank you for your answer! Actually, I woud like to start the color transition earlier. With your code, I can be notified when it starts/ends. But it doesn't answer my question. I think I need to look deeper in the source code.

Comment: The "animate" is almost always true, which causes the listener to be called very very often while scrolling. I think that in order to check the state change, you need to store the previous state. In addition, I can't see this as an answer to the question, as it doesn't allow you to control when to change the color.

Comment: @androiddeveloper Man that was so long ago... After reading everything again I guess there was a small misunderstanding of the question on my side as well.

Comment: @androiddeveloper I corrected the answer to correctly address the issue.

Comment: @BartekLipinski Nice. Sadly I actually found the previous code useful for something else I wanted. Can you please put a link to something similar to what you wrote? Or, edit the answer and just mark the old text as old answer or something?

Comment: @androiddeveloper sure I'm gonna restore the original question with the new one being an edit. Have a nice day!

Comment: @BartekLipinski Thank you very much.